# Connect two google forms to one google sheet and auto fill second form

Tags: google-sheets, qr-code, google-forms

We have two QR codes connected to two google forms. One is to sign in and collect keys and the second is to sign out and return the keys.

The first form is fine, the contractor fills out their name, company, phone and reason for the keys. When they scan the second QR code to return the keys I want to auto fill the information again from the google sheet so they don't have to and so they only have to tick a box confirming they have returned the keys.

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

I have been able to connect the two google forms to one google sheet but I am unable to auto fill the second form with the information from the linked sheet.

Comment: I am quite unsure with the process of how you want to retrieve data from sheets, is it by scanning the qr alone? by the way, will this be helpful: [How to create and send pre-filled Google Forms with the Google Sheets Substitute Formula](https://yamm.com/blog/create-pre-filled-google-forms-using-a-simple-google-sheet-formula/#:~:text=The%20SUBSTITUTE%20formula%20is%20used,Form%20from%20a%20Google%20Spreadsheet) Note: I am not affiliated nor the owner of the site.